# How To Hide Add Through Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have write a script which hide the ads but they are still running on the background but not displaying.

All i need is little bit of help through which i can fix this

```
<div>
<div style="display:relative;height:600:width:300;overflow:hidden">

<div class="cfmonitor"> 
// in the area advertisement code will be posted
</div>


</div>

<script>
document.mouseover=function(e){

var x=e.pageX;
var y=e.pageY;
document.getElementById('fbb').style.top=(y-15) + 'px';
document.getElementById('fbb').style.top=(x-40) + 'px';

}
</script>
</div>
```

through this add running in the header. but showing i want to hide but they should still run in the background

Comment: I don't get what you're asking for. Nor how this code-snippet is related to your request.

Comment: Please consider reformulating your question / or making a jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

write position:relative; instead of display:relative;

```
<div style="position:relative;height:600:width:300;overflow:hidden">
```